# Shortest distance around a pyramid

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

[image: Question]

Transcript:

> The diagram shows a square based pyramid with base PQRS and vertex O. All the edges are length 20 meters. Find the shortest distance, in meters, along the outer surface of the pyramid from P to the midpoint of OR.

The only way I have been able to solve this question is using a computer and the paper is non calculator, so there must be a faster, better solution.

My solution is creating a point X on OQ and labelling the midpoint of OR as M, and setting $\theta = OPQ$. I then calculated $PX + PM$ in terms of $\theta$ and found the minimum point of this function, in order to find the shortest possible distance. Finding the minimum point would be nowhere near possible under time constraint without a computer.

I have included the correct answer, so it is the working I am looking for.

Answer:

> D $10\sqrt7$

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Hint:**

The distance has to be a straight line along the net of the pyramid. There are two options:

[image]

The first line has lenght $10\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{3}}$, and the second one has $10\sqrt{7}$, which is the smaller one.

Comment: I'd also suspect you can't *dig* under the pyramid

Comment: Minor nitpick: Is it allowed to talk about *the* net of the pyramid?

Comment: Question: how do you reason about shapes that can not be flattened like such?

Comment: @orlp A curve of shortest distance which connects two points on a curved surface is called a [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic). Finding geodesics is in general nontrivial and involves solving systems of differential equations.

Comment: Supplementary question: is it true for all square-based pyramids, regardless of dimensions, that the shortest route will never involve "digging under" the base?

Comment: @mechanodroid Sorry I didn't necessarily mean a curved surface, just any shape that can't be flattened, such as the non-convex spiky tetrahedron.

Comment: @MichaelKay I think you can construct a hand-wavy proof by contradiction: suppose that were the case, projecting the route through the ground up onto the base of the pyramid would give a shorter route. Or were you thinking of traveling across the base as part of the 'outer surface'? (ie at the boundary between the base and the ground) I think the shortest path between two points on the perimeter of the base would be a straight line across the base, no?

Comment: @MichaelKay Counterexample: going from $P + \epsilon$ to $R + \epsilon'$ where epsilon just barely shifts the points on the surface faces. Ignoring their contribution, the shortest path over the pyramid's surface is $\sqrt{3}$ but the bottom is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, by "digging under" the base, I meant any route that involves a line in the plane of the base. We keep the part of the problem that says we're going from a base corner to half way up the opposite side; we just relax the constraint on the height of the pyramid (and for bonus points, the constraint that it's a right pyramid).

Comment: @MichaelKay The answer seems to be no. If $a$ is the base length, and $b$ side length, the route under the pyramid has length $$\frac{6a^2+b^2+2a\sqrt{4b^2-a^2}}4$$
and the route along the sides of the pyramid has length $\frac{9b^2}4-\frac{a^2}2$. Now consider $a = 1$, $b = 2$.

Comment: Of course, those are squared lengths.

Comment: Yes, the minimal distance is measured along straight lines on  faces of  its *development* (laid out  sides of pyramidal hollow box)

Answer (score 14):

Draw the net of the pyramid and use the cosine rule.
[image]

Comment: How do you know this is shorter than going through the square face?

Comment: @JiK, isn't it obvious? The hypotenuse of that right triangle is longer than 20 (longer than the length of the equilateral triangle)

Comment: Interestingly, if base length is $1$ and side length is $2$, the shortest route will be the one along the square face.

Comment: @JiK It isn't necessary to consider the square face as the problem statement talks about the outer surface of the pyramid. The way pyramids are usually displayed, a here, makes the outer surface not contain the base, which is the square.

Comment: @Ingix I don't understand. The outside of the square face is in the outer surface of the pyramid. How does the way it's displayed change it? Why can you use the PSO face, which is also hidden, but not the square face?

Comment: @Seyed It is definitely not obvious without actually calculating the distances (see mechanodroid's comment). Further, I don't quite understand what right triangle you're talking about.

Comment: @JiK, If you look at the "mechanodroid" drawing, the red line in that square is the hypotenuse of a right triangle with 20m and 10m sides. It is definitely obvious that in that triangle the hypotenuse is longer than 20m. Isn't it?

Comment: @Seyed $10\sqrt{7}$ is also larger than $20$, so I don't understand why it matters.

Answer (score 4):

***Hint:*** Draw the net diagram of the square pyramid and the you will find two points that are mid-point of $OR$. As you know that, minimum distance between any two points is the straight line joining them, just connect $P$ and midpoint of $OR$ by a straight line. Then just find the length of this line and exclude the length of this line that goes out of the net diagram. This length of line will be minimum length. Why?

Note: You can choose any one of the two midpoint because since the diagram is symmetric, the two lengths will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Cut along OQ and OR with a scissors, fold out that face to put the faces OPQ and OQR in one plane. Then the shortest path is a straight line from vertex P to the midpoint M of an opposite side of a 60-120 rhombus, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the black and blue lines as shown below:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

The length of blue line (using Cosine theorem):
$$c+d=\sqrt{20^2+y^2-2\cdot 20y\cos 60^\circ}+\sqrt{10^2+y^2-2\cdot 10y\cos 60^\circ}=\\
\sqrt{y^2-20y+400}+\sqrt{y^2-10y+100}$$
Set its derivative to zero:
$$(c+d)'=\frac{y-10}{\sqrt{y^2-20y+400}}+\frac{y-5}{\sqrt{y^2-10y+100}}=0 \Rightarrow \\
(y-10)^2(y^2-10y+100)=(5-y)^2(y^2-20y+400) \Rightarrow \\
3y^2-20y=0 \Rightarrow \\
y=\frac{20}{3}$$
Hence:
$$c+d=\sqrt{(\frac{20}{3})^2-20\cdot \frac{20}{3}+400}+\sqrt{(\frac{20}{3})^2-10\cdot \frac{20}{3}+100}=10\sqrt{7},$$
which is intuitively less since it passes through the two triangular faces while the black line passes through the quadratic base with larger area and the triangular face.

---

Anyway, to verify it, consider the length of the black line (using the Cosine theorem):
$$a+b=\sqrt{(20\sqrt{2})^2+x^2-2\cdot 20\sqrt{2}y\cos 45^\circ}+\sqrt{10^2+x^2-2\cdot 10x\cos 60^\circ}=\\
\sqrt{x^2-40x+800}+\sqrt{x^2-10x+100}$$
Set its derivative to zero:
$$(a+b)'=\frac{x-20}{\sqrt{x^2-40x+800}}+\frac{x-5}{\sqrt{x^2-10x+100}}=0 \Rightarrow \\
(x-20)^2(x^2-10x+100)=(5-x)^2(x^2-40x+800) \Rightarrow \\
13x^2-40x-800=0 \Rightarrow \\
x=\frac{20}{13}(1+3\sqrt{3})$$
Hence:
$$a+b=\sqrt{x^2-40x+800}+\sqrt{x^2-10x+100}=10\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{3}},$$